# Merge PDF files with same prefix using PyPDF2 Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have multiple PDF files that have different prefixes. I want to merge these pdf files based on the third prefix (third value in the underscore). I want to do this using python library PyPDF2.
This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    merger.append(filename)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 114, in merge
    fileobj = file(fileobj, 'rb')
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0_2021_564495_12345.pdf'

Process finished with exit code 1

For example:

```
0_2021_1_123.pdf
0_2021_1_1234.pdf
0_2021_1_12345.pdf
0_2021_2_123.pdf
0_2021_2_1234.pdf
0_2021_2_12345.pdf
```

Expected outcome

```
1_merged.pdf
2_merged.pdf
```

Here is what i tried but i am getting an error and it is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import io
import os
files = os.listdir("C:\\test\\raw")
x=0

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for filename in files:
    print(filename.split('_')[2])
    prefix = filename.split('_')[2]
    if filename.split('_')[2] == prefix:
        merger.append(filename)
    merger.write("C:\\test\\result" + prefix + "_merged.pdf")
    merger.close()
```

Comment: What error, what is 'not working'? [ask]

Comment: Isn't `if filename.split('_')[2] == prefix:` always `True`?

Comment: This is the error message

Comment: I have posted the error message.